# How do you unselect a row after closing a Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that opens when I click on a table row. When I click on the table row it highlights the row and opens the modal. If I close the modal I don't want the row to be highlighted anymore. I tried using the removeclass() method but that didn't work for me.

Here is my JS:

```
    $("#subJobs tr").click(function () {
        $("#subJobs tr").removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        
    });
    $('#jobModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        $("subJobs tr").removeClass("highlight");
        
    });
```

The first function adds the class "highlight" to the row that I select and the second function is supposed to remove it when the modal is closed. That's the one I'm having a problem with.

Comment: This is just a typo. You forgot the `#` selector prefix in second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the  `id` selector.

```
$('#jobModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#subJobs tr").removeClass("highlight");
});
```